# Entity Framework JSON Column Store data As UniCode in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, serialization, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

In a .NET 7 Web API project, I try to use EF7 JSON column to store translations of the entity.

These are my entities:

```
public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CardTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class CardTranslation
{
    public int laungaugeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDBContext> options) : base(options{}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Card>().OwnsMany(card => card.Translations).ToJson(); 
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

And in the `Post` action method, I accept the data in any language and in the `Get` action method also return data with the same language I entered for string values.

Sample of the request:

```
{
  "name": "你好",
  "translations": [
    {
      "laungaugeId": 0,
      "name": "你好"
    }
  ]
}
```

My issue with that : it stores data in SQL Server with Unicode as shown in the screenshot.

Could I configure serialization options to handle this issue?

[image: MsSql Server Table]

I'm expected to find the characters to be stored in the database as entered like English characters which is stored as is and doesn't get converted to Unicode

Comment: Welcome to the joy of System.Text.Json. _By default, the serializer escapes all non-ASCII characters. That is, it replaces them with \uxxxx where xxxx is the Unicode code of the character._ Ref: [How to customize character encoding with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/character-encoding)

Comment: Thanks For your advice but I try To set System.Text.Json Configuration In Program.cs Like Below And The Issue Still Exists. builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.WriteIndented = true;
    options.Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All);
});

Comment: currently there is no way to customize the serializer. Support for it is tracked here: [dotnet/efcore#28043](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28043)